# Android - how do I download my own paid app without paying?

Tags: android

Does Android allow me to download my own app without having to pay for it? :)

Or is there a 100% discount I can give myself? How do people usually handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just email yourself the apk file and download it and install it form there!

Comment: @Grrrrr is this different than installing the apk from a usb? I was able to run the app on my device, but it says my app is not actually installed. It is a bit strange.

Comment: @Genadinik It says it's different because the one from the market is signed with your release key, the one from the APK is signed with the debug key. Publishing it to the market may also mark it with some unique key that does not match the sideloaded version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot purchase your own app through Google Play. This is a [Google policy](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=141659).

You will have to side-load your app. If you are using the licensing server, this is not totally satisfactory, since Google Play will not respond to your installation in the same way that it will for purchased apps.

Comment: but I am able to get to the purchase screen....strange :) I didn't try to buy it just yet though...so not sure what will happen.

Comment: @Genadinik - I suspect that the sale will be blocked when you go to checkout. (This assumes that your account on your phone is tied to your publisher account. If Google thinks you are two different people, then of course the policy won't kick in.)

Comment: just tried it, and yes, it didn't let me. But for some reason it thinks that the install I made from the usb isn't the same install for this app.

Comment: @Genadinik - Did you install the published .apk file (the one you upload to Google Play) over the usb, or did you install the one signed by the debug cert (the one in your project's /bin directory)? That can make a difference.

Comment: I first installed an apk file from my usb. Then it worked so I uploaded that version live to Google Play.  Obviously that is being problematic.  How should I have done it?

Comment: @Genadinik - Are you using Google's licensing system? If not, then the only issue should be whether you signed the .apk with your publisher key. Can you elaborate on what the problem is with the side-loaded app?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you expecting, but there is a documentation in google play for consumer. It might help you

http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1751113